# C++: Reading multiple inputs only to end of the line

Tags: c++, cin

**How this program should work:**

> Enter 4 words:
>
> this is bad
>
> Bad input.

and

> Enter 4 words:
>
> hello you love it
>
> Good input.

**How I tried it:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
   cout << "Enter 4 words:" << endl;
   string a, b, c, d;
   cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
}
```

It reads input after end of the line and I can't figure out how to limit it only to one line. Can you please point me what function I should use? I'll be very grateful for every answer.

Thank you all!

Comment: Knowing about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::getline()` should be used when the program's expected input comes from an interactive terminal.

That's what `std::getline()` does: it reads text until the newline character. `operator>>` doesn't do that, that's what `std::getline()` does, and that's what should be used to process a line of typed-in text. Use the right tool, for the right job.

Sadly, many C++ books and tutorials introduce `>>` too early, before introducing `std::getline()`, and use it in their examples, simply because it's easier and more convenient to have `>>` handle the required data type conversion. Unfortunately, this results in a wrong mindset settling in, where `>>` is thought to be the automatic choice for processing interactive input. It is not.

The correct approach is to use `std::getline()`. Then, if necessary, construct a `std::istringstream`, and use that to handle any type conversions from the entered input. Not only does that solve the immediate problem, it also solves the problem of unparsable input putting `std::cin` into a failed state, with all subsequent attempted input conversions failing as well -- that's another common pitfall.

So, use `std::getline()`, first:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(void) {
   std::cout << "Enter 4 words:" << endl;
   std::string line;

   std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

And now, once the line of text is entered, it can be converted to a `std::istringstream`:

```
   std::istringstream i(line);
```

Followed by a loop to repeatedly invoke `>>` in order to count the words in this line. This part you can finish yourself.

P.S. Another common pitfall is `using namespace std;`. [You should not do that, as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The earlier good programming practices are acquired, the easier the subsequent road on the path towards C++ guru-ism will be.

Answer (score 0):

You should use following command:
`std::getline()`
This ignore the eventual space as a quote terminating string and you can store the value inside a variable, then see how much words are inside that.
Example:
`std::getline (std::cin,name);`